# Haxe (Flash) and inlining

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, inline, haxe

My question is about inlining in Haxe (AS3) in a few situation.

1. Will any method marked with the keyword `inline` (static and non-static), **always** get inlined during compilation?
2. Are properties inlined by default? If not, is there any way of inlining them? (Perhaps by assigning them inlined accessor methods)
3. If inlined methods disappear during compile-time, how come it's possible to derive functors out of them?

Answer (score 4):

have you looked at [inline doc](http://haxe.org/ref/inline) on haxe.org?

1.there (in the doc) are some restrictions on inlining functions. Besides you cannot inline recursive function. I belive all methods marked as `inline` will be inlined (of cause if there's no --no-inline oprtion in your hxml file), if some method with `inline` marker cannot be inlined an error will be thrown during compilation.

2.No they don't. You can inline only static vars otherwise you'll get a compilation error error (`Inline variable must be static`). Note that inlined var obviously cannot be changed, so there's no reason to inline non-static var. If you inline `geter` or `seter`:

```
private var v: Bool;

public inline function getv(nv: Bool) {
    return v;
}
```

it will be treated as:

```
private var v: Bool;

public inline function getv(nv: Bool) {
    return this.v;
}
```

after inlining `this` will be changed with reference to the class. Take a look at [example](http://haxe.org/doc/snip/stopwatch?lang=en). None of `StopWatched` class properties is inlined there.

1. I'm not sure I understand what is functor.

Comment: What I was referring to as inlined accessor methods was something like this: `public var x (getX, getY) : Int;`, where `getX()` and `getY()` are inlined methods. Also a functor is a function object. A methodology for passing function pointers around, for example to event listeners.

Comment: Acidic, I haven't really tested the results, but I recall they were inlined to some degree. They weren't when it involved interfaces, but that's quite obvious.

Comment: @Dykam Thanks for the reply. I am aware that inlined methods cannot be overriden, but that was not part of my question. The lack of documentation about such things annoys me quite a lot. My question is - are properties are really methods under the hood (like in C#), or are simply compiler restriction on field excess. (Talking about the normal properties, without using accessor methods.)

Comment: @Acidic, the property definition is nothing but an alias. It gets translated straight into a method call. And I think past that the usual function attributes apply.

Comment: @Dykam It doesn't seem that obvious due to the fact that you can attach accessor methods to the property or just have it 'as is'. The question is, whether using properties without attaching methods will generate methods under the hood (similar to automatic properties in C#) or will it behave just like a field but with customized visibility.

Comment: It will be a field with compile-time visibility checks. You can't mix and match accessor methods with defaults for this reason.

Comment: @Dykam How do you know? Is there any way to can check this? Or perhaps any mention of this in the documentation?

Comment: You can verify by checking the output when compiling to javascript. I don't know where I got it from myself, it's been a year since I used haXe.